# multiple call to a function to return a list of accumulated result

Tags: python, generator

try to loop in the main function, call to another function, at the end of the loop get a list of accumulative values:

code like this:

```
    def stock_stats(i):
      tmp=[]
      tmp.append(i+10)
      yield tmp

    def main():
       for stockid in total_nos_of_stock:
       stockinfo=readstock(stockid)     
       result=stock_stats(stockinfo)
       print(list(result))
```

expected result should be [stats for stock1,stats for stock2,...,stats for stockN]

try generator and closure, but didn't get it work.

i know i could append the values in the main loop or pass an empty list to called function, but i prefer most of the calculation in the called function and keep simple assignment in the main loop.

tkyou!

Comment: Why don't you pass `5` as an argument to `called_function`, which builds and returns the whole list? As it stands, `result` is assigned to a brand new list (containing only one item) on each call.

Comment: my project is that in the main function i loop thro 1200 nos of stock symbol, in each iteration i retrieve from web that stock info, then do some calculation and checking and put the result on a list. at the end of the loop i should get a list of stack of results. currently, i setup tmp=[] at the beginning and append the result to it for each iteration. but i rather like to move the calculation and checking to a separated function, call that function (result=called_function) every iteration and get the list at the end.

Comment: If you ask a question and the answers you get aren't helpful, you should consider whether or not the question is as clear as you thought it was. Please **edit the question** to better explain the issue.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm certain you were downvoted because this question needs improvement, nothing more. A lot of people have trouble writing questions. It's not a personal insult, so try not to take it as one. This question in particular, you have syntax errors (non-indented for loop), and while I haven't fully understood the problem yet, multiple people have noted that the question led them to believe your problem was something different than what it actually is. Please be more polite and understanding in the future, and please edit the details from your comment into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Statistician(list):

    KEYS = {'RSI':0, 'MACD':1, 'CAPRATIO':2, 'OTHER':3}

    def __init__(self):
        list.__init__(self)

    def read_stocks(self, stocks):
        for stock in stocks:
            self.read_stock(stock)

    def read_stock(self, stock):
        self.append(stock)

    def stock_stats(self, stock_info):
        if stock_info not in Statistician.KEYS.keys() :
            raise Exception('Unknow stock_info category. Please use one of the following value : {0}'.format(str(list(Statistician.KEYS.keys()))))
        return list(map(lambda x: x[Statistician.KEYS[stock_info]],self))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stocks = [('rsi1', 'macd1','capratio1','other1'),
              ('rsi2','macd2','capratio2','other2'),
              ('rsi3', 'macd3','capratio3','other3')]
    statistician = Statistician()
    for stock in stocks :
        statistician.read_stock(stock)

    print(statistician.stock_stats('RSI'))
    print(statistician.stock_stats('MACD'))
```

Execution :

```
python3 sof-script.py 
['rsi1', 'rsi2', 'rsi3']
['macd1', 'macd2', 'macd3']
```

Do this match your need ?

==================================================================================
EDIT : The same code using a closure form, as requested in comments.

Assuming that stocks are constant you could do that. This is the only way to use closure that make sense using this implementation. Other that use a given Statistician and read the blocks data inside the `collect` function require to use a `set` instead of a `list` in order to avoid side effect and data duplication.

```
stocks = [('rsi1', 'macd1','capratio1','other1'),
         ('rsi2','macd2','capratio2','other2'),
         ('rsi3', 'macd3','capratio3','other3')]

S = Statistician()
S.read_stocks(stocks)

#define a closure function        
def statisticCollector(statistician, key):
    def collect():
        return statistician.stock_stats(key)
    return collect

#instanciate the closed function
collectRSI = statisticCollector(S, 'RSI')
collectMACD= statisticCollector(S, 'MACD')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(collectRSI())
    print(collectMACD())
```

Comment: Replace `[i for i in generator]` by `list(generator)`.

Comment: Yep, it work as well. I like list construction using comprehensive for, but it's more readable in this case to use list.

Comment: pls look my comment at the top. range is not the real problem, just a sample. i rewrite the code to make  it look more realistic.

Comment: could you provide sample data ? Reading variable name used, it give me impression that you are trying to get in a list all the field stock from some data. If I'm wrong correct me : you use stock identifier in the `for` loop to retrieve informations about a particular stock. Then you store some statistics about this stock in the result variable using `stock_stats`, and at the end, the `result` variable contains information about every stock. Am I correct ?

Comment: @arthurVaisse, yes, you understand it correctly. to add a bit more, my scrip to loop thro all stocks, and in each iteration i calculate and check the stats for the stock, say rsi, macd, cap_ratio, etc. at the end of the loop, i should get a list for one stat for all stocks, e.g. rsi=[rsi for stock1, rsi for stock2, ...] i like to make the tedious calculation and checking in separation function, i know i could pass en empty list rsi=[] to the function and there appending the result to the list. but i prefer more neaty to make it like rsi=called_function in the loop. possible?

Comment: @arthurVaisse,cuz a nos of stats to be calculate, for now i have a nos of empty list at beginning of the main function, which does not look very nice.

Comment: @Arthur, tks for your answer. do u think it is possible to implement by using closure?

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up couple of concepts to the point that is hard to say what is wrong. Idea behind generators is that they produce series of values. It is pointless to just have a list at try to `yield` it. This is how you should really do it:

```
def called_function(source):
    for i in source:
        yield i + 10

def main():
    print(list(called_function(range(5))))
```

After reading your comment I guess that is what you really wanted:

```
def stock_stats(i):
  return i + 10

def main():
   result = []
   for stockid in total_nos_of_stock:
      stockinfo=readstock(stockid)     
      result.append(stock_stats(stockinfo))
   print(result)
```

Comment: pls refer to my comment at the top. my q is not about range, it is about get a list of result at the end of the loop in which i call the function every iteration.

Comment: @timeislove after reading your comment I think I understand what you meant. The question is completely misleading.

Comment: tks for your answer. this is exactly what i did before. but i  have a nos of stats to calculate hence a nos of empty list at the beginning and appending etc. that is not very neaty at all. is it possible to make things like result=stock_stats(stockinfo), at the end of the loop, i get the list of all results? that is to keep the appending in the called functions... or i have to create class for doing this thing? it looks to me what i should do is to keep the result of each call in the called_function, i thought of 'closure' but was not able to work thro it.

Comment: @timeislove I am sorry but I have hard time understanding what exactly you want here. I think you have something very trivial and just think too much about it and overengineer it.

Answer (score -2):

instead of sending each `i` send total range to the `called_function` . so that you can `yield` total list at a time

```
def called_function(n):
  yield list(range(10, 10+n))

def main():
      result=called_function(5)
      print(list(result))
main()
```

Comment: In this case, why would you `yield`? The function is done, just `return` it.